# Запись в базу даты последнего посещения ользователя

Tags: php, mysql

при авторизации значение $username присваевается к этому параметру  `$_SESSION['session_username']=$username;`
Вот код страницы пользователя.

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["session_username"])) {
    header("location:login.php");
} else {
?>
<h2>Welcome, <span><?php echo $_SESSION['session_username'];?>! </span></h2>

    <?php
    $session_username=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
    $query = mysql_query(("UPDATE usrtable SET usrlgntm=current_date WHERE username=".$session_username." LIMIT 1"),$con);  
    ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Этот код отображается без проблем

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['session_username'];?>
```

А вот этот код не отрабатывается. Запись в таблице в поле usrtable не появляется.

```
<?php
$session_username=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
$query = mysql_query(("UPDATE usrtable SET usrlgntm=current_date WHERE username=".$session_username." LIMIT 1"),$con);  
?>
```

Выдается такая ошибка

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Table 'nazdb.usrtable' doesn't exist' in /home/users/3/host1/domains/host1.reg.ru/intropage.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/users/3/host1/domains/host1.reg.ru/intropage.php on line 22
```

С таким кодом выдает

```
<?php
$session_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['session_username']);
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE usrtable SET usrlgntm=current_date WHERE username=`.$session_username.` LIMIT 1");
if (!$query) throw new Exception(mysql_error(), mysql_errno()); if (!mysql_affected_rows()) throw new Exception('not modified');
?>
```

Выдает такую ошибку

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unknown column '.user2233.' in 'where clause''

Пользователь user2233 в таблице usrtable в поле username есть и их там несколько с таким значением.

Comment: У вас в начале `$_SESSION["session_username"]`, потом `$_SESSION["username"]`

Comment: Исправил, все рано не отрабатывает.

Comment: После последних двух строчек вставляйте: `if (!$query) throw new Exception(mysql_error(), mysql_errno()); if (!mysql_affected_rows()) throw new Exception('not modified');` Потом смотрите в логи, если не понятно, дополняйте ответ

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Table 'nazdb.usrtable' doesn't exist' in /home/users/3/host1/domains/host1.reg.ru/intropage.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/users/3/host1/domains/host1.reg.ru/intropage.php on line 22

Comment: Кстати. Так конечно уже лучше, но все равно плохо: Пора переходить на темную сторону силы и использовать mysqli или PDO с ипользованием подготовленных запросов. Подстановка значений в запрос без экранирования спецсимволов - очень плохая практика.

Comment: А для того чтобы переписать код нужно просто в операторах сменить mysql на mysqli?

Comment: Это только для начала. Затем начинать использовать `mysqli_prepare()` и `mysqli_bind_param()` и не забывать обрабатывать исключительные ситуации. Можно это все собрать в самописный класс или использовать уже готовые решения

Answer (score 1):

Код рабочий, скопируйте его.

Если и он не будет работать, то у вас, наверняка, опечатка(и) в названии колонок бд.

```
$session_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['session_username']);
mysql_query("UPDATE usrtable SET usrlgntm = CURRENT_DATE WHERE username = '".$session_username."' LIMIT 1");
```

**UPD**. По ошибке из комментариев наглядно видно, что таблица с названием ***usrtable*** не создана.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unknown column '.user2233.' in 'where clause''

Comment: Теперь неизвестная колонка **_.user2233._**

Comment: Это не колонка а значение '".$session_username."'

Comment: @Михаил значит значение неверное.

Comment: @Михаил вы точно одиночные кавычки вставили? Просто если их нету, то значение вашего параметра воспринимается как поле таблицы

Comment: Да, они стоят. Сделал запрос в phpmyadmin, отработал без проблем.

Comment: @Михаил попробуйте `WHERE username = '$session_username' LIMIT 1`